# Laggy/choppy sound in bluetooth devices after a while without sound reproduction

Tags: 16.04, sound, bluetooth

I haven't found a solution for this issue, the other entries I found about choppy or laggy sound are about the sound always being like that or because interference.

The sound in my bluetooth devices is flawless when I pair them or turn them on, the issue always happens after a few minutes without sound reproduction, the sound starts to lag, if I pause videos or music, it needs a moment to stop reproducing sound because it's out of sync.

The only solution I came with is to reset the bluetooth device (earphones or speakers), if I turn off the bluetooth card or disconnect/reconnect the device from the built in bluetooth manager the issue remains. Even though it's a fixable issue, it is very annoying to turn off and on the device everytime that I need to pause my music or leave my workstation.

In [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179209) macOS solution in apple stackexchange, it says something about:

> "an issue with the amount of power/bandwidth supplied to the **BluetoothAudioAgent**, the daemon in charge of streaming."

I tried to find something similar in Ubuntu 16.04 with no luck, I'm guessing it's a similar issue that might be happening with my bluetooth card configuration for example.